# jquery pageChange is not triggered on android 2.2

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

We are developing a Cordova based Android application.
All HTML pages are local(in `assets/www` folder).
We load HTML pages using jquery mobile changePage method and register for events(button click events etc) in `pageChange` callback.

For android 2.3 and above this works fine, requested page is loaded and events(click events etc) are binded properly.

**On Android 2.2 we are facing an issue**, on `changePage` method call requested page is loaded but `pageChange` event is not fired(so click events are not binded properly).

Any idea what could be causing this?
Is there are issue with `changePage` on lower versions of android?

Comment: Can you show us your javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if **[pageChange](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/)** event is working on an Android 2.2 but there are some easy  workarounds.

**[Pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)** can be used instead. It is last event to trigger before **[pageChange](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/)** triggers so it can also be used for event binding.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 

});
```

One last thing, you don't need to wait for **`changePage`** to bind click events. You can use something called [**delegated event binding**](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events). For it to work it doesn't matter if object exists in DOM or not because event will be binded to the document. It will propagate to element only when such need exists, for example if object is clicked.

This is how you do delegated event binding:

```
$(document).on('click', '#elementID', function(){ 

});
```

Comment: Tried using delegated event binding, it works(so we no longer need a callback to register for click/tap events). But we still need a callback pageshow/pagechange to work to update UI(based on some conditions if required) or initialize some data.

Comment: I guess in pagebeforeshow  UI elements of requested page are not in DOM and we will not be able to alter their properties

Comment: They are at DOM even during first pagebeforecreate event. Pagebeforeshow should be used to add / modify content because page is about to be show.

Comment: Tried pagebeforechange and pagebeforeshow one by one. In both cases, first page is loaded and click/tap events registered in pagebeforechange/pagebeforeshow. But when i try to launch second page(on a button click), second page did not load and no callback was fired. Same set of changes work fine on 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I think it's high time you drop support to Android 2.2. Even PhoneGap officially deprecated the support to Android 2.2. Only less than 5% use [Android 2.2 and below](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

In my experience I usually use `pagecreate` event to bind events for buttons etc. This event is fired once the page is created. Try the method below on Android 2.2 and see whether it helps you out.

You can do something as below

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#myPageID', function(){
 //Registering button click
 $('#myButton').bind('click',function(){
   alert('button click');
 });
});
```